# Nuget restore for dependent projects

Tags: nuget

I have multiple projects in a added in multiple solutions and at different directory levels. I use packages.config to maintain list of dependencies. 
On nuget restore for a solution through command line, packages folder is created in the same directory as solution file and gets all dependencies are downloaded. Now there are some projects added as reference which are also present in other solutions. So projects refer different packages folder. On restore only 1 packages folder is created and so some projects referring packages at other location, do not get their packages restored.

Is there any way one can get all dependencies in multiple packages folder in different directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a NuGet.Config file with a `repositoryPath` which overrides the default behaviour.

```
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
    </config>
</configuration>
```

The path is relative to where the directory the NuGet.Config file exists.

Note that the location of the NuGet.Config file should be in a directory that is the same or above the solutions. Whilst you can have multiple NuGet.Config files, it will probably be simpler to have one at the root directory of your solutions. For example:

- /Your/Projects/Test/NuGet.Config
- /Your/Projects/Test/MySolution.sln
- /Your/Projects/Test/Another/MySolution2.sln

Also note that you would need to reinstall the NuGet packages in the projects, or at least fix the reference paths, since they will now be using a different packages directory and will be incorrect.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now this is integrated with Jenkins and the repo path is not considered. Packages are downloaded at solution  level and not on repo path. @Matt would you have info on that. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If the build server is using NuGet to restore the solution then it should find the NuGet.Config file if you have it in the solution's directory. If you are putting this into the user profile's NuGet.Config file (~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config) then I would move the file so it is with the source code.